# Я хочу вернуть уникальных авторов с его самой длинной книгой и названием этой книги. должно быть 3 колонки в ответе

Tags: mysql, sql

У нас есть таблица под названием «книги», которая содержит столбец названия книг, столбец имени авторов, столбец номеров книг и т. д.

Я попробовал этот вариант:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(
        author_lname, ' ', author_fname
    ) AS author,
    MAX(pages),
    title
FROM books GROUP BY author;
```

Но он работает с семантической ошибкой, я имею в виду, что он дает уникальному автору самую длинную страницу, но с другим названием книги

P.s. есть некоторые авторы, повторяющиеся несколько раз в колонке авторов с названием их разных книг [image: Эта картина просто для справки]

Буду признателен за любые варианты исправить это

Comment: This is russian community SO, please russian!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow in Russian. As its name implies it's a _Russian_ speaking community so please post in Russian here. I guess you know Russian so it wouldn't be a problem for you to translate the question. Alternatively you can ask on the main English StackOverflow. Thanks.

Comment: Я извиняюсь за ошибки, просто не обратил внимание, сейчас исправлю 